# Could Someone Explain an Ordered Field in Layman's Terms?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, real-numbers, ordered-fields

High school student here...

I am currently working on Spivak and I'm not very far (just reached questions in chapter 1). I was discussing my progress with someone recently and they asked me to explain why $\Bbb C$ can't be an ordered field like $\Bbb R$. I had recently read Spivak's proof that the square of any nonzero number is always positive, so after some thinking, I concluded that $\Bbb C$ can't be an ordered field because $i^2 = -1$. The person who asked me the question told me I was correct and at first I was very happy. Then I realized I still don't know what the heck an ordered field is. I looked it up on Wikipedia and I couldn't really get an idea of what the article meant. Spivak doesn't cover fields until chapter 27 and I feel like I wouldn't really get it by skipping there. Could someone give a layman-esque overview of what an ordered field is and why $\Bbb R$ is one *really*?

Comment: Good that you are interested in mathematics. Spivak is a wonderful book! Enjoy it, and don't give up when things get harder!

Comment: @Math_QED I can say that the few questions I've completed so far have already done a great deal for my intuition. I enjoy seeing the proofs behind many of the facts I had accepted as axioms in my algebra and calculus classes.

Comment: Excellent! Reading that book this early can only benefit you. When you come at the "limit chapter", the book becomes a lot harder, but also more interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a couple of examples in your mind throughout this post (and generically). A field is roughly something that behaves like the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$, the reals $\mathbb{R}$, or the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. There are other fields, but these are the ones which you are probably most familiar with.

More generally, a field is a set of things in which it makes sense to add two things together and multiply two things together. Both of these operations should be commutative, meaning that $a+b = b+a$ and $ab = ba$. Further, there is a distributive law connecting addition and multiplication, so that you have $a(b+c) = ab + ac$.

A field should also have two distinguished elements, that we might suggestively call $0$ and $1$, so that $a+0 = a$ for all $a$ and $ b*1 = 1$ for all $b \neq 0$.

Finally, for every $b \neq 0$, there should be another element $b^{-1}$ such that $bb^{-1} = 1$.

In other words, a field is a set where addition and multiplication work essentially as they work in $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{C}$.

---

Now one should note that not all fields really do look like $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{C}$. Some fields have could have weird definitions of "multiplication" or "addition" --- what's important isn't that they're exactly the same, but that they behave in ways similar to the fields we're very familiar with.

---

Returning to the question at hand, we now know what a field is. An ordered field is a field where you can say, for any two elements $a$ and $b$, whether $a < b$, $a = b$, or $a > b$. And this should be in such a way that the typical ideas we have about inequalities hold true. These ideas include

- $1 > 0$
- if $a > b$ and $b > c$, then $a > c$
- if $a > 0$ and $b > c$, then $ab > ac$

and things of that nature.

Comment: Don’t think your last bullet is quite right.

Comment: Thank you! Of course you're right.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I now see how ordered fields relate to the conversation I was having about Spivak :D Thank you for the detailed response.